# RedisTemplate nullPointException

Tags: java, redis, jedis

I am working with jedis and redisTemplate library but when I declare hashoperations ***hashOps*** and trying to get values, I came up with NullPointExteption.

```
    
      RedisTemplate<String, String> redisTemplate2 = new RedisTemplate<>();


      JedisConnectionFactory jedisConnectionFactory = new JedisConnectionFactory();
      jedisConnectionFactory.setUsePool(true);
      jedisConnectionFactory.setHostName("100.100.101.102");
      jedisConnectionFactory.setPort(9999);  
      
      redisTemplate2.setConnectionFactory(jedisConnectionFactory);
      redisTemplate2.setDefaultSerializer(new StringRedisSerializer());
      
      System.out.println(redisTemplate2); 
      HashOperations<String, String, String>  hashOps = redisTemplate2.opsForHash(); 
      List<String> result = hashOps.values("chat_content:");
```

On the last line I got Null Exception. Neither redisTemplate nor jedisConnectionFactory are empty. Am I missed Something??? Any help would be thanks

Comment: I think that the exception says that `keySerializer` is null. Did you try to set it by calling to `setKeySerializer` method?

Comment: You get an entire stack trace, which you did not include.

Comment: Can you provide the full stack?